# Library to do SCP for C#

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, scp

Is there a library that provides the ability to do SCP transfers in C#?

Comment: I found this library: https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have you tried [SharpSSH](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sharpssh/)? (last update was 2013)

Comment: Since that library seems not to be maintained anymore, the best guess today probably is http://sshnet.codeplex.com/ , which is based on SharpSSH and has commits from 2014. (I am just struggling to make SharpSSH work in certain scenarios.)

Comment: @Tobia: Not having used SharpSSH much myself, I can't confirm that. Given that in 2014 there was a suggestion that SharpSSH was no longer maintained, I probably wouldn't try now anywya.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I moved to https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET

Answer (score 6):

Use [WinSCP .NET Assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library). It is really straight forward.

Comment: It should be noted that the WinSCP .NET Assembly also requires WinSCP installed.  It is not a standalone library.

Comment: @NathanLewis, so how can we get that WinSCP?