# PuTTY in C# for file transfer

Tags: putty

Can any one help me with a code snippet in C# for transferring a file on my local machine to a remote server using PSCP (PuTTY) transfer methodology? I would really appreciate the help.
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [SCP for C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651399/scp-for-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a library that support SCP like [SSHNet](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/) or [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library). Both provide samples and tests that demonstrate how they work.

With SSH.Net you can upload a file using this code (from the test files):

```
using (var scp = new ScpClient(host, username, password))
{
    scp.Connect();
    scp.Upload(new FileInfo(filename), Path.GetFileName(filename));
    scp.Disconnect();
```

}

With the WinSCP library the code looks like this (from the [samples](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library#csharp)):

```
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions {
            Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
            HostName = "example.com",
            UserName = "user",
            Password = "mypassword",
            SshHostKey = "ssh-rsa 1024 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
};

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    // Connect
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    // Upload files
    TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
    transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;

    TransferOperationResult transferResult;
    transferResult = session.PutFiles(@"d:\toupload\*", "/home/user/", false, transferOptions);

    // Throw on any error
    transferResult.Check();

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am still confused about my needs. The client is asking that they need to transfer the files using the PuTTY SCP technology. I don't know how this is differenct from the other SCP technology. Can you or somebody else please tell me or explain what should I do in this case? I appreciates your replies. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using `SFTP` and `SCP` supported clients with .NET Libraries might be the best option. But here is a simple way to use `PSCP`:

```
Process cmd = new Process();
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\PuTTY\pscp.exe";
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
string argument = @"-pw pass C:\testfile.txt user@10.10.10.10:/home/usr";
cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = argument;

cmd.Start();
cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
string output = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```