# Connection to ESXi 6.0 and file transfer in C# using ScpClient

Tags: c#, ssh, scp, esxi

I want to connect to Esxi 6.0 hypervisor and upload a file. I use SSH net from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472633/putty-in-c-sharp-for-file-transfer).

```
        using (var scp = new ScpClient("10.8.58.26", 22, "root", "MyPasword"))
        {
            scp.Connect();
        }
```

But I am getting "No suitable authentication method found to complete authentication." exception. SSH on hypervisor is On and manually i can connect using putty or winscp. I tried this with linux and it is working.
How should i properly authenticate to esxi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Futher research gives me: "ESXi does not use a full featured ssh-server like the well known openssh. It instead uses a lightweight version which is build into Busybox."

I figure it out on my own. I use winscp library instead of scp. Code looks like this:

```
SessionOptions sessionOptions= new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
    HostName = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
    UserName = "root",
    Password = "MyPasword",
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
};

private void WinScp(SessionOptions sessionOptions, string sourceFilePath, string destinationFilePath)
        {
            using (Session session = new Session())
            {
                // Connect
                session.Open(sessionOptions);

                //// Upload files
                TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
                transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;

                TransferOperationResult transferResult;
                transferResult = session.PutFiles(sourceFilePath, destinationFilePath, true, transferOptions);

                //// Throw on any error
                transferResult.Check();
            }
        }
```

SshHostKeyFingerprint  can be find in "Customize System/View Logs" -> "View  Support Information" of ESXi.